# How to use custom authentication/authorization in an ASP.NET Core MVC app that communicates with a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use the authentication/authorization in an MVC/Razor Page app which uses a back-end API to transact data and authentication tokens. The API issues access and refresh JWT for valid sign in and what I have done so far is to call the API and fetch these tokens using HttpClient and afterwards, store them in cookies.

However, I have to manually check for the tokens and refresh the access token when it expires and also delete the cookies when user signs out. I would like to know if there is a way to use this in more proper method by utilizing the authentication and authorization features of ASP.NET Core (such as using [Authorize] to limit certain controllers' to specific users.

Comment: Do you need an access token for each individual user, or is it shared access?  Does user authentication occur locally or remotely?

Comment: and whats wrong with the build in one?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Identity Server](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/), which is both and Authentication (using OpenIdConnect) and an Authorization server (using OAuth).

Then in your WebApp (MVC/Razor and client of the API) simply use its integration. An example of how to setup an ASP.NET MVC as a client of an IdentityServer instance can be found in Identity Server's official [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html#creating-an-mvc-client).

For the refresh token, you need to configure your MVC app to request the `offline_access` scope.

Comment: IdentityServer is a good choice but it doesn’t do authorisation.

Comment: It does do OAuth yes which can authorise an app to access resources elsewhere, I was referring to [this](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/amp/).